# How to print string with a carriage return

Tags: go

I have a string which ends with a carriage return:

```golang
        str := "my data\r"
```

If I try to print that string, using:

```golang
        fmt.Println(str)
```

all it shows is an empty line. How do I make it output full string, like "my data", without trimming the last character (carriage return)?

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense. What "last character" is being trimmed? What output do you expect? What do you actually see instead?

Comment: Which OS and terminal emulator are you using? In mine it shows "my data" followed by the invisible `\r`, followed by a single line break (probably because it treats Windows style newlines the same as Linux style).

Comment: I use emacs-terminal. Which apparently does not print data before the carriage return. Now I tested with gnome terminal and it prints. Thanks @peter

Comment: emacs-terminal probably treats the carriage return like it worked traditionally: return the carriage and start overwriting the line.

Comment: yup I guess so too

Comment: please clarify the question, What is your need??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by Emacs terminal, which discarded data printed before carriage return.

Using gnome-terminal fixed it. Thanks for your help @peter